# Check string unicode "non-western" SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode, amazon-redshift

I am trying to count the names which has "non-western" characters in my table.

I am using the following but it does not work:

```
select count(id) 
from table 
where name != cast(name as varchar(1000))
```

Is there any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if DVT solution did not work for me because I am trying it on Redshift or not. 
Anyway I manipulated his solution to be accepted with redshift logic and it works as following:

```
select count(*)
from table
where ( name !~*  '([A-Z].*)' )
```

[for more details](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using regular expression with the exclusion (^). (Thank you Tyron and Damien for pointing out my error and provide the solution to it).

```
select count(id) from table 
where name LIKE ('%[^0-9abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]%')
```

Check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx
(Below is the content copied from the link)

[^] Any single character not within the specified range ([^a-f]) or set ([^abcdef]).    WHERE au_lname LIKE 'de[^l]%' all author last names starting with de and where the following letter is not l.

Comment: shouldn't it be "NOT LIKE"?

Comment: @Tyron78 He wants a a string with **a** non-western character. And there is a '^' to denote that it has a character not among 0 to 9, a to z, ...

Comment: Sorry - my fault! Didn't notice the ^

Comment: @Tyron78 NP. I should modify the answer to be clearer.

Comment: But nevertheless: somehow it still seems to be faulty... I tried the following two statements and the result is the same... SELECT CASE WHEN 'Tyron' LIKE ('%[^0-9a-zA-Z]%') THEN 'NOT WEST' ELSE 'WEST' END AS x
SELECT CASE WHEN 'TyronÄÖÜßáóé' LIKE ('%[^0-9a-zA-Z]%') THEN 'NOT WEST' ELSE 'WEST' END AS x

Comment: @Tyron78 Thanks. I'll recheck.

Comment: Unless you're using binary collations, the order of characters can be quite surprising. I wouldn't be at all surprised to find e.g. `é` in the range `a-f`, probably somewhere quite close to `e`. Notably, most collations do *not* follow ASCII order.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Exactly as you said. Fixed it.